Parameterized Gates
I am trying to create my own custom parameterized gate and then  transpile it to the AerSimylatorGate. I have been able to create the virtual circuit but in the transpilation to the backend basis set I encounter the error TranspilerError: 'HighLevelSynthesis was unable to extract definition for custom: ParameterExpression with unbound parameters (dict_keys([ParameterVectorElement(theta[0])])) cannot be cast to a float.'. I share the code:
class DiagonalGate(Gate):
def __init__(self, num_qubits: int=None ,params: ParameterVector=None, label: str=None):
    super().__init__('custom',num_qubits, params, label=label)
def _define(self):
    from qiskit.circuit.library import UnitaryGate
    defn = QuantumCircuit(2)
    unitary_array = np.zeros([len(self.params), len(self.params)])
    for i in range(len(self.params)):
        unitary_array[i][i] = self.params[i]
    diagonal_gate = Operator(unitary_array)
    defn.append(diagonal_gate,[i for i in range(self.num_qubits)])
    self.definition = defn
def __array__(self, dtype=None, copy = None): # This enables the Gate.to_matrix() code line
    if copy is False:
        raise ValueError('unable to avoid cioy while creating array request')
    unitary_array = np.zeros([len(self.params), len(self.params)], dtype=complex)
    for i in range(len(self.params)):
        unitary_array[i][i] = self.params[i]
    return unitary_array
def to_matrix(self) -> np.ndarray:
    unitary_array = np.zeros([len(self.params), len(self.params)], dtype=complex)
    for i in range(len(self.params)):
        unitary_array[i][i] = self.params[i]
    return unitary_array

Now the code for the circuit and transpilation:
thetas = ParameterVector(name='theta',length=4)
diag_gate = DiagonalGate(num_qubits=2,params=thetas)
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(diag_gate,[0,1])
backend = AerSimulator()
transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc,backend)

I need the daigonal to be Parameters so I can run a variational algorithm on this ansatz.
Does anyone know if I can create my own parameterized gate from an operator? I have seen that many people try to express this matrix as a series of different predefined qiskit gates, however i don't see how I can accomplish this.
